# Does $f_k(x):=\frac{1}{x^{1+\frac{1}{k}}}$ converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

> Let be $f_k:[1,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f_k(x):=\frac{1}{x^{1+\frac{1}{k}}}$. Does this sequence converge uniformly?

**My approach:**

It is easy to see that $(f_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges pointiwsely to $f:=\frac{1}{x}$. Also
$$
\left|\frac{1}{x^{1+\frac{1}{k}}}-\frac{1}{x}\right|\leq \frac{\left|x^{\frac{1}{k}}-1\right|}{x}.
$$
Though it seems that the upper bound goes to $0$ independent from $x$, which would allow me to say something like $\sup\{|f_k(x)-f(x)|\mid x\in[1,\infty)\}=0$, I am not able to carry it out rigorously.

Do you have any hints? Maybe there is a tricky manipulation which might help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x \ge 1$ and $k \ge 1$ is, using [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#Real_exponent),
$$
 x \le x^{1+1/k} = x (1+(x-1))^{1/k} \le x \left(1 + \frac{x-1}{k}\right) \, .
$$
It follows that
$$
0 \le \frac 1x - \frac{1}{x^{1+1/k}} \le \frac1x \left( 1 - \frac{1}{1+(x-1)/k}\right) = \frac{x-1}{x(x-1+k)} \le \frac 1k
$$
and that proves the uniform convergence on $[1, \infty)$.

We can also start with your estimate:
$$
\left|\frac{1}{x^{1+\frac{1}{k}}}-\frac{1}{x}\right|\leq \frac{x^{\frac{1}{k}}-1}{x} = \frac{(1+(x-1))^{1/k}-1}{x}
\le \frac{(x-1)/k}{x} \le \frac 1k \, 
$$
again using Bernoulli's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Your bounding functions,  $g_k(x):= \frac{x^{1/k}-1}{x}$ is differentiable in the domain and attains the maximum in some interior point $x_k$.  Differentiating it gives you that $x_k= \big( \frac{k}{k-1} \big)^{k}$.

Therefore, $\sup_{x\geq1}  g_k(x)=g_k(x_k)$. You just have to check whether $g_k(x_k)\to0$. You can see that

$$ g_k(x_k)= \frac{ \big( \frac{k}{k-1} \big)^k-1 }{\big( \frac{k}{k-1} \big)^k}= \frac{ \frac{1}{k-1} }{ \big( 1+ \frac{1}{k-1} \big)^{k-1} \cdot \big( \frac{k}{k-1} \big)}\to \frac{0}{e\cdot 1}=0. $$

This gives you another way to show uniform convergence.

Comment: Not sure but I guess your $x_k$ should rather be $x_k=\left(\frac{k}{k-1}\right)^k$. This allows as to express $g_k$ by a product of a zero sequence and $e^1$ which yields a zero sequence.

Comment: @Philipp You're right, I miscalculated.  What you said is what I might meant up to my miscalculation.